# linux ls -ltr sort by name

Tags: sorting, unix, ls, file-listing, file-sorting

I see many questions on this site on `ls` sorting
But what I need is a sorted output  `ls -ltr` (sorted by file name)
Because I need the file sizes and dates as well for comparison.
I tried `| sort -k`, `| sort`, `ls-1ltr` without success.

This is the unsorted list:

```
ser@xeroxsqa02:/app/java/jars> ls -ltr
total 41940
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xeroxadmin mqm  331471 May 10  2017 spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xeroxadmin mqm  153115 May 10  2017 jdom-1.1.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xeroxadmin mqm  185140 May 10  2017 commons-io-2.4.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xeroxadmin mqm  279193 May 10  2017 commons-lang-2.5.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xeroxadmin mqm  489884 May 10  2017 log4j-1.2.17.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xeroxadmin mqm   53081 May 10  2017 spring-asm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xeroxadmin mqm 2095932 May 10  2017 ojdbc5-11.2.0.3.0.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xeroxadmin mqm    4467 May 10  2017 aopalliance-1.0.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xeroxadmin mqm   38460 May 10  2017 joda-convert-1.2.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xeroxadmin mqm 1891110 May 10  2017 guava-13.0.1.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xeroxadmin mqm  589824 May 10  2017 spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xeroxadmin mqm  449324 May 10  2017 spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xeroxadmin mqm  232019 May 10  2017 commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xeroxadmin mqm  831068 May 10  2017 spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xeroxadmin mqm  569231 May 10  2017 joda-time-2.0.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xeroxadmin mqm   52915 May 10  2017 commons-logging-1.1.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xeroxadmin mqm  107225 May 10  2017 spring-context-support-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xeroxadmin mqm  176311 May 10  2017 spring-expression-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
drwxr-xr-x 2 xeroxadmin mqm      46 Jun 30  2017 bkp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xeroxadmin mqm 1599570 Jan 17 19:12 axis-1.4.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xeroxadmin mqm   79796 Jan 17 19:12 commons-discovery-0.5.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xeroxadmin mqm  148429 Jan 17 19:12 wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar
```

Comment: This makes very little sense. `-t` sorts by mtime, and `-r` reverses the sort order, but since you don't care about mtime there's absolutely no need to invoke `ls` with either of those options.

Comment: sorry, you are correct, what i meant is that i need the same output as the command ls -ltr and not just flat ls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried following:

```
ls -lru
```

Per man page:

> `-u`     with `-lt`: sort by, and show, access time; with `-l`: show access time and sort by  name;  otherwise:  sort  by access time, newest first

Comment: Awesome, not sure how I missed that! thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Set Environment variable $LC_COLLATE to appropriate value 
eg.

```
    LC_COLLATE=en_US ls -l1va
```

In shell scrip,set at startup

```
    export LC_COLLATE=en_US
```

Answer (score 0):

`ls -ltr -a` can help too. It is including hidden files starting with a `.`